# How to implement passport in a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following [this tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport). I've installed *passport* using composer as well. But when I run this command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

It throws:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: cre
>     ate table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) n
>     ot null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varc
>     har(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set
>     utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> In Connection.php line 458:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

Any idea how can I fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are at initial stage of your project remove users table and its corresponding migration table row from migrations table an run passport install.

Comment: The problem is, after `composer require laravel/passport`, I don't see any migration file in `database/migrations/` directory for *passport* library. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Your migrations table missed some migration results. You must delete user table manually from the database and then try again "php artisan migrate".

You can delete table easily with the thinker

```
php artisan tinker

Schema::drop('users')
```

Answer (score 0):

The first you can config connect database, the secon you open foler project\app\Providers and edit file AppServiceProvider.php the following below, now you can run php artisan migrate again

```html
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```